# In my rails 7 app, audio recording when stopped, preview does not work in iphone. but works on android,mac

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html5-video, audio-recording

> this is my audio preview partial which shows the preview of audio which is recording: **I am creating custom controls, icons and js functions to record audio and show its preview then publish it.
> It is recorded, but when preview is showing it is not playing on the iPhone but can be downloaded.
> It is working fine on any Android phone, PC, Mac but not on iPhone.
> audio preview partial:

```
<audio id="audio-preview" preload="auto">
  <source src="myaudio.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
<div class="custom-audio-controls">
  <div class="play-pause-button" onClick="toggleAudio()">
    <%= image_tag "play.png", id:"play-pause-icon" %>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="custom-progress-bar">
      <div class="custom-progress-fill"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="audio-time-display">0:00 / 0:00</div>
  <div class="download-button" onClick="downloadAudio()">
    <%= image_tag "icons8-download-48.png", id:"download-icon" %>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio-preview');
  var playButton = document.querySelector('.play-pause-button');
  var playPauseIcon = document.getElementById('play-pause-icon');
  var progressBar = document.querySelector('.custom-progress-bar');
  var progressFill = document.querySelector('.custom-progress-fill');
  var audioTime = document.querySelector('.audio-time-display');
  var downloadButton = document.querySelector('.download-button');
  var isPlaying = false; // Track the play/pause state

  function toggleAudio() {
    if (!isPlaying) {
      audio.play();
      playPauseIcon.src = '/assets/pause.png';
      isPlaying = true;
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      playPauseIcon.src = '/assets/play.png';
      isPlaying = false;
    }
  }

  function updateProgressBar() {
    var duration = audio.duration;
    var currentTime = audio.currentTime;
    var progress = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
    progressFill.style.width = progress + '%';

    var minutes = Math.floor(currentTime / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(currentTime % 60);
    var totalTime = Math.floor(duration);
    audioTime.textContent = minutes + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds + ' / ' + totalTime;
  }

  function downloadAudio() {
    var source = audio.querySelector('source');
    var audioUrl = source.getAttribute('src');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = audioUrl;
    a.download = 'myaudio.wav';
    a.click();
  }

  audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgressBar);
</script>
```

audio-recorder page:

```
    <div class="create-upload-audio">
      <div class="create-upload-heading">Click to reply</div>
      <div class="create-videos-wrap">
        <button class="record-audio">
          <label for="record-audio">
            <%= image_tag "icons8-voice-recorder-50.png" %>
          </label>
          <span>Record Audio</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="record-audio-wrap">
    <div class="voice-recorder">
      <div class="audio-progress-bar">
        <div class="voice-record-button">
          <%= image_tag("icons8-record-64 (1).png", alt: "Record", class: "icon") %>
        </div>
        <div class="voice-pause-button"> <%= image_tag("icons8-stop-48.png", alt: "Stop", class: "icon") %></div>
        <div class="progress-bar">
          <div class="progress"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="time">0:00 / 0:00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="audio-preview">
      <%= render 'expert/questions/audio-preview' %>
      <div class="audio-controls">
        <div class="publish-audio" onClick="publishAudio()">
          <%= image_tag "publish-video-icon.svg" %>
          Publish
        </div>
        <div class="delete-audio" onClick="deleteAudio()">
          <%= image_tag "delete-video-icon.svg" %>
          Delete
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".record-audio-wrap").hide();
      $(".record-audio").on('click', function() {
        $(".main-content").hide();
        $(".record-video-wrap").hide();
        $(".uploaded-videos").hide();
        $(".record-audio-wrap").show();
        $(".audio-preview").hide();
      });

      const audioPreview = document.getElementById("audio-preview");
      const recordButton = document.querySelector(".voice-record-button");
      const stopButton = document.querySelector(".voice-pause-button");
      const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress");
      const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time");
      const publishButton = document.querySelector(".publish-audio");
      const deleteButton = document.querySelector(".delete-audio");

      let mediaRecorder;
      let audioChunks = [];
      let startTime;

      async function startRecording() {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: true
        });
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
          if (event.data.size > 0) {
            audioChunks.push(event.data);
          }
        };
        mediaRecorder.onstart = () => {
          startTime = Date.now();
          updateProgressBar();
        };
        mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
          const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
            type: "audio/wav"
          });
          audioPreview.src = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
          progressBar.style.width = "0";
          timeDisplay.textContent = "0:00 / 0:00";
          $(".voice-recorder").hide();
          $(".audio-preview").show();
          $(".delete-button").show();
          $(".publish-button").show();
        };
        mediaRecorder.start();
      }

      function stopRecording() {
        if (mediaRecorder.state === "recording") {
          mediaRecorder.stop();
          audioChunks = [];
          clearInterval(progressInterval);
        }
      }

      let progressInterval;

      function updateProgressBar() {
        progressInterval = setInterval(() => {
          const currentTime = Date.now() - startTime;
          const formattedTime = formatTime(currentTime);
          timeDisplay.textContent = formattedTime + " / 0:00";

          const progressBarWidth = (currentTime / 10000) * 100;
          progressBar.style.width = progressBarWidth + "%";
        }, 100);
      }

      function formatTime(ms) {
        const seconds = Math.floor(ms / 1000);
        const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        return `${minutes}:${remainingSeconds < 10 ? "0" : ""}${remainingSeconds}`;
      }

      recordButton.addEventListener("click", startRecording);
      stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopRecording);

      publishButton.addEventListener("click", publishAudio);
      deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteAudio);
    });

    function publishAudio() {
      $(".audio-controls").addClass("d-none");
      $("#upload-progress").removeClass("d-none");
      $(".upload-progress-wrap").removeClass("d-none");
      const progressBar = $("#upload-progress");
      const uploadValue = $(".upload-value");
      progressBar.val(2);
      progressBar.css("width", "2%");
      uploadValue.html("2%");

      $(".progress-bar .progress").css("width", "2%");

      const audioPlayer = document.querySelector("#audio-preview");
      fetch(audioPlayer.src)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
          const file = new File([blob], 'audio.wav', {
            type: 'audio/wav'
          });
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("upcoming_question[audio]", file, 'myaudio.wav');

          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

          xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
              const percentComplete = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
              progressBar.value = percentComplete;
              progressBar.style.width = percentComplete + '%';
              uploadValue.innerHTML = percentComplete + '%';
            }
          });

          xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadHandler);
            window.location = "/expert/questions/upcoming";
          });

          xhr.addEventListener('error', function() {
            console.error('An error occurred while uploading the audio.');
          });

          xhr.open('PATCH', `/expert/questions/${<%=@question.id%>}/attach_response`);
          xhr.send(formData);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));

    }

    function deleteAudio() {
      const audioPlayer = document.querySelector("#audio-preview");
      audioPlayer.src = '';
      $(".audio-preview").hide();
      $(".voice-recorder").show();
      $(".delete-button").hide();
      $(".publish-button").hide();
    }

    function beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = '';
    }
</script>
```